# convert a hexadecimal file and extract / display characters that belongs to a language

Tags: python, unicode

I am parsing files with consists of ascii characters but in hexadecimal format such as A is represented as 65 in the file. 
so the file content looks like this:

```
60 42 00 64 62 D6 52 20 4E 65 75 2D 55 6C 6D 20 2F 20 45 76 C4
```

I am trying to extract useful information out of the file which belongs to a language set.
I have no idea how the file has been saved ( if it is utf-8 or utf-16 )
I am trying to write a python program and my first approach was to combine the whole line, so that it looks like this

```
fd = open('file.txt', 'r')
x = fd.readline()
x_split = x.split(' ')    
x_split = ', '.join(x_split)
x_split = x_split.replace(', ', '\\x')
x_split = u'\\x'+ x_split   
# here the line should look like '\x60\x42\x00\x64\x62\xD6\x52\x20\x4E\x65\x75\x2D\x55\x6C\x6D\x20\x2F\x20\x45\x76\xC4'
print x_split               
# here i assumed that the above hexadecimal numbers would be shown as alphabets.
```

I was assuming that it should return me the characters such as Abcd etc. but rather the print printed the whole line again ( in numbers ) what was present in the file.

Comment: Really Robert Harvey? Unclear? This seems totally clear to me - how do you convert a list of hex numbers into bytes?

Comment: P.S. there might be less confusion if you took the references to languages out of the question. There appear to be two parts to the problem, and you should tackle one at a time.

Comment: Could even be iso-8859-2...

Comment: well the point is when I do print line = '\x60\x42\x00\x64\x62\xD6\x52\x20\x4E\x65\x75\x2D\x55\x6C\x6D\x20\x2F\x20\x45\x76\xC4', I successfully see the following on the output `B dbÖR Neu-Ulm / EvÄ. But as soon as I write a program which generates the same line, then the print does not return me anythi8ng useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not producing bytes which can be decoded into strings; you're just making a string with a lot of `\` and `x` characters before letters and numbers.

```
>>> x = "60 42 00 64 62 D6 52 20 4E 65 75 2D 55 6C 6D 20 2F 20 45 76 C4"
>>> x_split = x.split(' ')    
>>> x_split = ', '.join(x_split)
>>> x_split = x_split.replace(', ', '\\x')
>>> x_split = u'\\x'+ x_split   
>>> x_split
u'\\x60\\x42\\x00\\x64\\x62\\xD6\\x52\\x20\\x4E\\x65\\x75\\x2D\\x55\\x6C\\x6D\\x20\\x2F\\x20\\x45\\x76\\xC4'
```

Again, that's just a string with a bunch of characters. That some of them happen to be the same ones used in hexadecimal is basically irrelevant.

If you want an array of bytes, you could instead do something like

```
>>> bb = bytearray(int(b, 16) for b in x.split())
>>> bb
bytearray(b'`B\x00db\xd6R Neu-Ulm / Ev\xc4')
```

and then if you know the encoding, you can get something out of this.  For example, here's one random guess:

```
>>> bb.decode("iso-8859-2")
u'`B\x00db\xd6R Neu-Ulm / Ev\xc4'
>>> print bb.decode("iso-8859-2")
`BdbÖR Neu-Ulm / EvÄ
```

but different assumptions about the encodings will give different results.  (A rough analogy: unless you know whether the single word "confetti" is in English or Italian, you won't know whether it's referring to those little bits of paper tossed around in celebration or sugared almonds.)